# Clone and edit kie tools to custom BPMN/DMN editor

Tags: bpmn, kie, dmn, kogito

I am new in developing BPMN/DMN editors. I have come across the kie-tools git repository which has editors base code as they specify.
But I couldn't find any documentation which I could follow to start editing the code and achieve my changes. It mentioned Jboss Uberfire, but that too seems very hazy as there are a large number of packages being initiated parallel in the repository once we build.
Any support on the same might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

First of all let you know that there exist 2 repositories that contains the BPMN/DMN editors, depending on the environment:

- If you're using the BPMN/DMN editors for Business Central, the repo is [1]
- If you're using the BPMN/DMN editors for VSCode, the repo is [2]

There actually no exist detailed developer guides, but for getting started with the editors and its code, you can use the README's. For instance, when coding for the BPMN editor (VSCode), you can start by reading [3]. In case of coding with the BPMN editor (Business Central), it's basically same procedure but instead of pointing repo [2], you have to point repo [1].

If you feel comfortable with this coding environment and want to do any customization on editors, please let us know which are your goals. This way, once clear, a ticket can be opened, and we will provide technical feedback for developers, targeting on the concrete goals, and providing directions and guidance.

Thanks in advance!

[1] https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-wb-common/

[2] https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-tools/

[3] https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-tools/tree/main/packages/stunner-editors/kie-wb-common-stunner/README.md

Comment: I have the need to add the kie bpmn and dmn editor to my app, with some UI customizations of my own accord. I have been trying to do that with edits to the stunner editor and standalone editor. But its very confusing